# Android Studio Countdown Timer

Tags: java, android, timer, countdown

So I am working with Android Studio and I need a countdown timer.
So far i have searched and found all kinds of code lines that do not work , or do not do exactly what I wanted the app to do.
I want the timer to countdown , if the user answers incorrectly , the time left will be reduced , and if the user answers 3 correct , then time will be added.
Can anyone give me a code and explain what it does , do I need anything extra?
and how i can modify it to my needs.

Comment: Show us what you have tried..

Comment: Where is your code snippet? Add your code, whatever you have tried as of now

Comment: @weston, bad boy, don't be sarcastic... ;-)

Comment: @pskink I was going for pedantic, but removed anyway!

Comment: @weston come on, it was just a joke ;-)

Comment: @pskink don't worry mate, I'm not upset :) I removed as it wasn't a very helpful comment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the official countdown timer from Google. Look here:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html

```
new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {

    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        mTextField.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
    }

    public void onFinish() {
        mTextField.setText("done!");
    }
}.start();
```

And then you can manually add/reduce your time with every wrong answer.

Comment: And do I need to add extra packages or imports?

Answer (score 0):

I can't post a command so have to do it this way.

I think this is wat your looking for:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html

millisUntilFinished will contain the amount of time that is left, So lets say you want to add 5seconds on a correct answer you could do something like

```
    switch CorrectAnswer
    {
      case "1"
          millisUntilFinished + 5000;
          break;
      case "2"
          millisUntilFinished + 10000
          break;
      case "3"
          millisUntilFinished + 15000
          break;
    }
```

Where 1, 2 and 3 are the amount of correct answers, same would work for. This code would not work like this but it will give a general idea of how it could work.